# In MFC CTreeCtrl how to disable/skip hot tracking style for some items?

Tags: mfc

In my MFC `CTreeCtrl` I am using `TVS_TRACKSELECT` style.

I want to skip or disable this style for some items in my Tree control.

How to achieve it?

Comment: You could try `TVIS_EX_DISABLED` [item state](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773459(v=vs.85).aspx). If this doesn't fit your needs, you propably have to use custom draw.

Answer (score 0):

My question was answered in this link

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7e362437-0c9b-4994-84d8-4322666cb5cd/remove-or-draw-without-tvstrackselect-for-some-items-in-ctreectrl-using-nmcustomdraw?forum=vcgeneral#f9242eed-091e-4359-978d-19bcdfcb74e9

Comment: It's usually a good idea to post code & not just a link, because link may die one day & your post become non-helpful.